# Excel adjust to non-active worksheets while looping through directory

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro to loop through directory and put data in my master file. The masterfolder contains all information about employee hours spend on a specific project. However, the sheet name of the employee hour files (non-master files) might differ. I managed to change this for the activesheet (master sheet) but I'm not sure how to adjust this for the non-active (non-master) sheets (in formula this specific sentence: `Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Sheets("Sheet1")`

```
    Option Explicit

Sub CopyToMasterFile()

    Dim MasterWB As Workbook
    Dim MasterSht As Worksheet
    Dim MasterWBShtLstRw As Long
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim TempFile
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook
    Dim CurrentWBSht As Worksheet
    Dim CurrentShtLstRw As Long
    Dim CurrentShtRowRef As Long
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    Dim wbname As String
    Dim sheetname As String

    wbname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name

    FolderPath = "C:\test file\"
    TempFile = Dir(FolderPath)

    Dim WkBk As Workbook
    Dim WkBkIsOpen As Boolean

    'Check is master is open already
    For Each WkBk In Workbooks
        If WkBk.Name = wbname Then WkBkIsOpen = True
    Next WkBk

    If WkBkIsOpen Then
        Set MasterWB = Workbooks(wbname)
        Set MasterSht = MasterWB.Sheets(sheetname)
    Else
        Set MasterWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & wbname)
        Set MasterSht = MasterWB.Sheets(sheetname)
    End If

    ProjectNumber = MasterSht.Cells(1, 1).Value



    Do While Len(TempFile) > 0

        'Checking that the file is not the master and that it is a xlsx
        If Not TempFile = wbname And InStr(1, TempFile, "xlsx", vbTextCompare) Then

            Set CopyRange = Nothing

            'Note this is the last used Row, next empty row will be this plus 1
            With MasterSht
                MasterWBShtLstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End With

            Set CurrentWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & TempFile)
            Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

            With CurrentWBSht
                CurrentShtLstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row
            End With

            For CurrentShtRowRef = 1 To CurrentShtLstRw

             If CurrentWBSht.Cells(CurrentShtRowRef, "AE").Value = ProjectNumber Then

               'This is set to copy from Column A to Column L as per the question

               If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                 'If there is nothing in Copy range then union wont work
                 'so first row of the work sheet needs to set the initial copyrange
                  Set CopyRange = CurrentWBSht.Range("AE" & CurrentShtRowRef & _
                                                ":AQ" & CurrentShtRowRef)
                Else
                  'Union is quicker to be able to copy from the sheet once
                  Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, _
                                        CurrentWBSht.Range("AE" & CurrentShtRowRef & _
                                                            ":AQ" & CurrentShtRowRef))
               End If  ' ending   If CopyRange Is Nothing ....
             End If ' ending  If CurrentWBSht.Cells....

            Next CurrentShtRowRef

            CopyRange.Select

            'add 1 to the master file last row to be the next open row
            CopyRange.Copy
            MasterSht.Cells(MasterWBShtLstRw + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            CurrentWB.Close savechanges:=False

        End If     'ending            If Not TempFile = "master.xlsx" And ....

        TempFile = Dir

    Loop

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to refer to a worksheet, without knowing their names in advance:

```
'To get a specific worksheet:
Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Worksheets(10)
'To get the last worksheet:
Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
'To get the pre last worksheet:
Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count-1)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It's that easy, I was thinking too complicated I suppose, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the workbook only has 1 sheet then you can simply do this:

```
Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Sheets(1)
```

If there are more than 1 sheet in the 'non-master' workbook, you could have this:

```
Set CurrentWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & TempFile)
Dim oWS As Worksheet

' Loop through all sheets to find the sheet we want
For Each oWS In CurrentWB.Worksheets
    If oWS.Name = sheetname Then
        Set CurrentWBSht = oWS
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

You could add a flag in the loop above to confirm if you found a sheet
Also, from what I can see, your macro is in your master sheet?. If that's the case, you don't need to do the check if the 'Master workbook' is open. You can just use **`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name`** (`ThisWorkbook` is the object for the workbook where your macro is running from)